# multi thread synchronize two method java

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a multithreaded server and request are coming to server.
There is a scenario like we have two types of client.

One is customer
Other is admin

Customer can send request
Customer can cancel request
admin can accept request

there are two different function

One is cancel request function which is method A
other is accept request function which is method B

Some time customer request it is marked as pending.
Now admin respond with accept and meanwhile customer cancel

so admin think he accept the request
and customer think he cancel the request.

so is there anyway to synchronize the cancel and accept method.

```
//Cancel Request
public void A() {
    int currentrequeststate = app.sharedData().getMap("users").get(user_id); //let say this is read as pending
    if (currentrequeststate == RequestState.PENDING) {
        currentrequeststate = RequestState.CANCEL;
        app.sharedData().getMap("users").put(user_id, currentrequeststate);
        //cancel it and sending cancel message
    }
}


//Accept Request
public void B() {
    int currentrequeststate = app.sharedData().getMap("users").get(user_id); //there is a chance this also read as pending
    if (currentrequeststate == RequestState.CANCEL) {
        //sending no trip to accept might be canceled
    } else {
        currentrequeststate = RequestState.ACCEPTED;
        app.sharedData().getMap("users").put(user_id, currentrequeststate);
        //Accept it and sending accept message
    }
}
```

as there will be multiple thread and both method can be run by differnt thread concurrently.
so there is a chance that both method read current currentrequeststate as pending
the first Method A will cancel the request
the second Method B will accept the request

Comment: You have lots of bugs here; not only synchronization is your problem.

Comment: sorry i put 
String currentrequeststate = app.sharedData().getMap("users").get(user_id); 
where it is 
int currentrequeststate = app.sharedData().getMap("users").get(user_id);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not fully familiar with the exact problem which you're
solving but I would try something along these lines below.

1. I would use an array `str` of type `String[1]` for the statuses, and not just `String`s; this way I won't change ever the reference `str` which I synchronize on (all I change is the `String` object that `str[0]` points to).
2. This also allows me to execute two methods `A` at the same time by different threads, if they are in the context of different `user_id`s. My synchronization is on `str` i.e. per `user_id` only. I don't block threads on `A` if they do calls for different `user_id`s. Actually I think `user_id` should be parameter of these two methods.
3. Note how I am comparing Strings (by using equals, not ==)
4. I assume the PENDING, ACCEPTED, CANCELLED, etc. constants in `RequestState` are Strings. If this assumption is not true, just rework the code slightly following the same logic.

   ```
   // Cancel Request
   public void A() {
       String[] str = app.sharedData().getMap("users").get(user_id);
       synchronized(str){
           String currentrequeststate = str[0];
           if (RequestState.PENDING.equals(currentrequeststate) {
               str[0] = RequestState.CANCELLED;
               // cancel it and sending cancel message
           }else if (RequestState.ACCEPTED.equals(currentrequeststate)){
               // throw exception here (or take whatever action appropriate)
               // as this request was already accepted by the admin;
               // so it is too late for the user to cancel it
           }
       }
   }


   // Accept Request
   public void B() {
       String[] str = app.sharedData().getMap("users").get(user_id);
       synchronized(str){
           String currentrequeststate = str[0];
           if (RequestState.CANCELLED.equals(currentrequeststate)) {
               // Already cancelled, admin cannot accept it now as it's too late;
               // so take whatever action is appropriate in this case
           } else {
               str[0] = RequestState.ACCEPTED;
               // OK, accept it and sending accept message
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: "I would use an array str of type String[1] for the statuses, and not just Strings; this way I won't change ever the reference str which I synchronize on (all I change is the String object that str[0] points to)."

i did not get idea why you are doing this

Comment: Because this way `str` remains constant, we never change it.

Comment: and also i am only allow to store json in map which mean i have to save immutable object in map ?

Comment: As I wrote I am not familiar with all your details (as you did not provide them). Use my answer as an idea, a sketch, rather than as a final/literal solution. Given the current state of your question, I doubt anyone would be able to provide a final/literal solution.

Comment: thanks :) i appreciate your help. let say i am only allow to store json in the app.sharedData().getMap("users") map. so then what will i need to do with this.

Comment: Well, I guess you can either use this map (with the JSON data) if you can... Or you would need to define another map/structure for keeping the user request statuses and also for thread synchronization purposes.